# Copy Files from One Drive to Another and Keep Hard-Link in Windows

Tags: ntfs, robocopy, hardlink

I have drive A: with 16G Space and plenty of files, due to the Hard-link feature in NTFS, the files together is 15G but only takes 2G of real space.

I like to copy all those files to drive B: which is a 4G USB disk, and formatted as NTFS

A: is a tool set in local disk, B: is USB disk for distribution. So I cannot use a bigger USB disk (for the reason of cost), and B: should have all files that can work on another computer.

I tried: robocopy, rsync of windows, and plenty of other disk-clone, backup solution etc.

None work, all simply give out of space error.

My question: how can I copy the files from A: to B: and keep of the hard-link structure?

Any solution welcome, as long as not reboot to non-windows or something. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Same question: http://superuser.com/questions/997190/copy-to-another-ntfs-disk-and-preserve-hard-links

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [ln.exe](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html) with "Smart Copy" function `--copy`?

> Smart Copy basically creates a copy of the directory structure from the source location to the destination, but it preserves the inner hardlink structure and inner junction/symbolic link relations of the source, and recreates this inner hardlink structure and inner junction/symbolic link relation at the destination location
>
> Smart Copy is a must if e.g. the whole content of a hard disk, which has lots of hardlinks/junctions/symbolic links, should be copied to another hard disk.

Comment: I found a software "Shadow Copy Cloner" can do what I want :)

Comment: www.goldentroutsoftware.com/scc.html‎

Comment: @EricYin Dead link

Comment: ln.exe crashes consistently for me about 180GB into a copy of a 260GB folder ... any alternatives would be welcome

Comment: Succeeded with cygwin rsync as described in the other thread

Comment: @EricYin - Could you share a copy of this dead link SW?

Comment: I just tried this, and I could move files and hardlinks wherever I wanted (i.e. to other folders or other drives; rename the source files, move only the hardlinks to another folder etc.pp.) -- and all hardlinks still kept working. For the copying, I tried both Dopus and Explorer, without difference. I wonder whether this has changed in the meantime, such that the problem in the OP does not exist anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Third party copy utilities do exist that can handle hardlinks. Look for mention of 'hard links' and possibly 'reparse points' in their documentation to help you identify if a utility can handle it.

Comment: :( Tried many, none works

Answer (score 0):

FastCopy claims to handle hardlinks:
https://fastcopy.jp/help/fastcopy_eng.htm#hardlink

Answer (score 0):

strarc can do it

`strarc64.exe -cjd:src_dir | strarc64.exe -xd:dest_dir`

http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/